# Find volume of object given a triangular mesh

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, cgal, marching-cubes

I have an object defined by vertices and triangular faces.

```
verts = [[0.1, 1.,  1. ]  [1.,  1.,  0.1]  [1.,  0.1, 1. ]  [1.,  1.,  1.9]  [1.,  1.9, 1. ]
 [1.9, 1.,  1. ] ]
```

And triangular faces, which define the vertices composing each faces:

```
faces = [[ 2,  1,  0]  [ 0,  3,  2]  [ 1,  4,  0]  [ 0,  4,  3]  [ 5,  1,  2]  [ 3,  5,  2]
 [ 5,  4,  1]  [ 4,  5,  3]]
```

I can create a mesh using Poly3DCollection

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
mesh = Poly3DCollection(verts[faces])
```

I can use `mesh` to plot the object in 3D. Is there a way in python to then find the volume of this object? Papers ([here](http://chenlab.ece.cornell.edu/Publication/Cha/icip01_Cha.pdf), [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gregory_Nielson/publication/3736980_Interval_Volume_Tetrahedrization/links/57fd511308ae406ad1f3d080/Interval-Volume-Tetrahedrization.pdf), and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0387)) indicate it is possible. If not in python, are there methods in other languages that make this possible (i.e. that you know of). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this using `meshplex`

```py
import meshplex
import numpy as np

verts = [[0.1, 1.,  1. ],  [1.,  1.,  0.1],  [1.,  0.1, 1. ],  [1.,  1.,  1.9],  [1.,  1.9, 1. ], [1.9, 1.,  1. ]]
faces = [[ 2,  1,  0],  [ 0,  3,  2],  [ 1,  4,  0],  [ 0,  4,  3],  [ 5,  1,  2],  [ 3,  5,  2], [ 5,  4,  1],  [ 4,  5,  3]]

mesh = meshplex.MeshTri(np.array(points), np.array(faces))

V = np.sum(mesh.cell_volumes)

print("Volume =", V)
# Volume = 5.6118446
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, CGAL is able to compute the volume of a triangulated mesh with this function : 
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__measure__grp.html#ga85cebf8fbc7cb8930fd16aeee2878c7e

Sadly I don't think it has been ported in python.

Comment: There actually is a port, [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh), which I am using. Just wish the tutorial was easier to follow! I'll consider the question answered :)